# enlarge height of row after div element in row enlarge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have in one row some div elements (similar like tiles). In this my tile I have some title and button. So when I click in this button in some tile, it will be shown description of product. When I have multiple lines of "tiles" and when I click on description button some of them, I want to enlarge height of row where this tile is situated. Now it only move down only tile, which is under element on which I clicked. How to do it? My code:

```
<div class='row'>
@foreach($devices as $device)
<div class='col-sm-3'>
    <div class='tile'>
        <p class='title'> {{$device->type}} </p>
        <div class='detail' style="text-align:center;"> 
            <a href='#'>
            <img src='img/show_more.png'
                 width='20' height='20' > 
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            {{ $device->description }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

and my script.js

```
$('.description').hide();

$('.detail').click(function(){
   $(this).siblings('.description').toggle(); 
});
```

Comment: Maybe a JSFiddle example would be nice to go with this question. There is only one row and all tiles are in it? Multiple lines are because of tiles number in that one row?

Comment: tried to recreate the sitiuation but your question is still not clear - http://codepen.io/dex3844/pen/ZOwZPx